# XCode 6 - interface builder Cocoa touch cool freeze when compiling

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, interface-builder, xcode6

I am compiling a project (I use cocoapod) with multiple storyboard and the xcassets file. But during the process, it's freezing and all my RAM get full and also my hard drive (with a swap file). It's a real problem, I can compile anymore !!!! (both simulator and device)

In the activity monitor, I can see appear a program : "Interface builder cocoa touch tool" during the compiling process. It appears in multiple instance and it's very consuming of the processor.

If I kill the most consuming process, I get the "ibtoold code 255" error.

I get this error is the console : 
10/10/2014 01:51:08,584 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[28150]: assertion failed: 13F34: libxpc.dylib + 29453 [XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX]: 0x8d

Anyone has the same problem ?

Xeonarno

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169559/xcode-6-build-hangs-and-interface-builder-cocoa-touch-tool-starts-allocating-al