# UIDatePicker on iPad Showing Interface Issues with iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios7, uidatepicker

I have a simple app that's built with the iPhone. I have a `UIDatePicker` with a custom background that looks great.

[image]

However, the same component with (what I can see are the same settings) on the iPad in the storyboard looks like this when the app is run:

[image]

I have gone through the storyboard many times for the iPhone and iPad and all of the settings are the same. I just cannot see what I'm doing wrong or what needs to happen to get this weird interface issue fixed.

It's an iOS 7 app built with Xcode 5.1. I don't have the ability to test out Xcode 6.0.1 because of this issue that I'm facing: [Xcode 6: Build hangs and Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool starts allocating all RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169559/xcode-6-build-hangs-and-interface-builder-cocoa-touch-tool-starts-allocating-al).

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 I have the same issue. Never really fixed it but when I change the date, then the color changes.

Comment: Thanks - thats exactly the same with me. It's bizarre. Have you managed to test this out on Xcode 6? I'm unable to test on that at the moment.

Comment: In iOS 8, the whole month "column" has the incorrect background color but the day and year have the correct background.

Comment: Damn that's so weird man

Comment: I'm upgrading my app for iOS 8 in a few weeks. I will revisit this issue then and let you know if I find a fix.