# Xcode hanging, runs out of memory when using Bindings and IB

Tags: cocoa, core-data, swift, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I have a core data model with two entities, for the sake of this post I will call them Category and Items, Category is the parent entity with a one-to-many relationship to Items.

In IB I have a NSTreeController and NSOutlineView that manages the Category entity, this works great.
I also have an ArrayController with Mode set to Entity, Entity Name set to Items, Content Set bindings set to Tree Controller with Controller Key of "selection" and Model Key Path set to the relationship.

I have tested all this works by selecting Categories in the outline view and outputting how many Items are available inside the array controller when I change selection from the tree controller using the following code:

SWIFT:

```
  @IBOutlet var itemsArrayController: NSArrayController!

    @IBAction func logResult(sender: AnyObject) {

        println("Items Array has \(itemsArrayController.content?.count) records")

        // Print first item to console
        var anItem : Items! = itemsArrayController.content?.objectAtIndex(0) as Items

        if let something : Items = anItem? {
                         println(something.name)

        }

    }
```

Now I want to hook up a Table View to the Array Controller that will list all the Items of the selected Category.

So If I bind Table View Cell's Value to **Items Array Controller.arrangedObjects.name** and click RUN xcode starts compiling and just doesnt proceed past 50%.  Activity Monitor->Memory shows "ibtooid" with 5GB of memory after awhile before the entire system locks up and I have to hard reset my mac.  Even if I click stop in Xcode the ibtooid continues to eat memory,  The only way to stop from a hard reset is to kill that process,.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1046a)

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169559/xcode-6-build-hangs-and-interface-builder-cocoa-touch-tool-starts-allocating-al

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the table to Cell based rather than View Based.  Will file a bug with Apple.